# Loop until element equals to specific text in drop down

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I have the following piece of code

```
Do
    On Error Resume Next
    .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_DropDownListl2").AsSelect.SelectByText ("txt")
    On Error GoTo 0
Loop Until .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_DropDownListl2").AsSelect.SelectedOption.Text = "txt"
```

I have a lot of drop down lists that I deal with them with the same approach and although I used On Error Resume Next, I got errors sometimes and I have to wait a little and click Resume to resume the code execution
Can I make this as public procedure as I will use such lines a lot with other elements?
And how I can avoid the errors? and of course at the same time get my target for selecting the desired text in the drop down

Here's a snapshot of one of the errors
[image]

Based on @QHarr reply I tried to make a public procedure like that

```
Sub WaitElement(driver As Selenium.WebDriver, sElement As SelectElement, txt As String)
Dim t           As Date
Const MAX_SEC   As Long = 30

With driver
    On Error Resume Next
        t = Timer
        Do
            DoEvents
            sElement.AsSelect.SelectByText txt
            If Timer - t > MAX_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop Until sElement.AsSelect.SelectedOption.Text = txt
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

End Sub

But when trying to use it in that way

```
WaitElement bot, .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_DropDownListnat"), ws.Range("B11").Value
```

I got 'Run-time error 13' (Type mismatch)

After applying the UDF named 'TextIsSet' I got this error 
[image]

and the same problem.. if I click on Debug then Resume then wait a little, the code resumes its work

I have used such lines too but doesn't help

```
        Do
    Loop While .FindElementsById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Dschool").Count = 0
```

I got the same last error of not founding such an element

Comment: "how I can avoid the errors?" - how can we know unless you describe those errors?  As for how to make this into a separate sub - there are only two variables in that code, so those would be obvious candidates as parameters in your sub.

Comment: The errors related to selenium that those elements that need waiting time .. even with the existence of the Do Loop Until .. I have to click Resume to make the code work and resume work

Comment: I have attached an error .. I think it is a matter of waiting as when I click Debug then Resume .. the code works after a while

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when an action causes a change to the DOM. The lazy way is to add a timed loop to try for that element until that error goes away or time out reached. You could also try shifting the On Error to surround the loop instead of inside the loop and then add in a time out. This is a little brutal but without a webpage to test with.

As a function call (this feels ugly and you may find webElements don't like being passed around):

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 30
    'other code
    If TextIsSet(dropdown, expectedText, MAX_WAIT_SEC) Then

    End If

End Sub

Public Function TextIsSet(ByRef dropdown As Object, ByVal expectedText As String, ByVal MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long) As Boolean
    Dim t As Date
    On Error Resume Next
    t = Timer
    Do
        DoEvents
        dropdown.AsSelect.SelectByText expectedText
        If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
    Loop Until dropdown.AsSelect.SelectedOption.Text = expectedText
    If dropdown.AsSelect.SelectedOption.Text = expectedText Then
        TextIsSet = True
    Else
        TextIsSet = False
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

---

I don't have a stale element test case so I just used a drop down test case:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 30
    Dim d As WebDriver, expectedText As String, dropdown As Object
    'expectedText = "AL - Alabama"  ''Pass Case
     expectedText = "Bananaman" 'Fail Case
    Set d = New ChromeDriver

    With d       
        .get "https://tools.usps.com/zip-code-lookup.htm?byaddress"           
        Set dropdown = .FindElementById("tState")  
        'other code
        If TextIsSet(dropdown, expectedText, MAX_WAIT_SEC) Then
            Debug.Print "Tada"
        Else
            Debug.Print "Sigh"
        End If
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub

Public Function TextIsSet(ByRef dropdown As Object, ByVal expectedText As String, ByVal MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long) As Boolean
    Dim t As Date
    On Error Resume Next
    t = Timer
    Do
        DoEvents
        dropdown.AsSelect.SelectByText expectedText
        If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
    Loop Until dropdown.AsSelect.SelectedOption.Text = expectedText
    If dropdown.AsSelect.SelectedOption.Text = expectedText Then
        TextIsSet = True
    Else
        TextIsSet = False
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my tutor. I have a lot of elements with the same error .. so using such lines for each element will be painful ...!

Comment: Thank you very much. I have attached an error after applying this change

Comment: I will have a look. You have changed something as mine shouldn’t throw an error due to the ugly all encompassing on error resume next.

Comment: I have not changed anything. I have used the UDF as it is .. The drop down is a javascript element that filled with options .. is that make difference?

Comment: you have a sub. See my udf above.

Comment: I am confused. All errors are suppressed in the function and only a boolean returned. Not sure how you can generate that error with my code. You can always add an err.clear at the very end but I don't think that makes a difference.

Comment: Most of times those drop down lists are empty and they are filled with options based on other drop lists .. Can the number of options checked too to make sure the drop down is ready for selecting from it?

Comment: yes.... and you have done something similar before...you use the FindElementsByCss .Count